# React useState working other then expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm just going throught a webdevelopmnet course and found an interesting thing where I dont know what is happening behind the scene and why both solution work:
the task was that a ul item strikethroughed on/off when it is clicked.
so i just added a simple formating with ternary operator

`<li>onClick={handleOnClick}style={{ textDecoration: isClicked ? "line-through" : null }} </LI>`

The part I don't understand why both solution for isClicked works:

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
```

First version:

```
function handleOnClick(){
setIsDone(prevValue => {return !prevValue})
}
```

Second version:

```
  function handleOnClick()  
    setIsClicked(!isClicked); 
  }
```

Why is the second solution working without passing by the previous parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you change the state you are queuing that state change. The problem with this state queue is that is flushed asynchronously. So, the API gives you two options, one that is not concurrency safe and another that it is. The second version you mentioned is not concurrency safe, given it changes the state from the current state; not from the previous state as the concurrency safe option.

So, if you use the second version and start queueing lots of state changes in a short span, you could end up with an undesired final state.

As in your example, you may want state changes that depend on the last change, somethings like this:

```
false->true->false->....->true
```

The second version cannot ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

useState have a default parameter current State you can either use that i.e first version

```
function handleOnClick(){
setIsDone(prevValue => {return !prevValue})
}
```

or use state directly by its name i.e second

```
function handleOnClick()  
    setIsClicked(!isClicked); 
  }
```

Comment: in current case state can either be true or false
prevValue have the current State if its false ! will turn it to true viceversa

Answer (score 0):

It's related to SCOPE in JS:

Example:

```
var carName = "Volvo";

// code here can use carName

function myFunction() {

  // code here can also use carName

}
```

For your case: when you clicked, variable isClicked is also prevValue.